# connection between integral of perodic function and the sum of integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, summation, laplace-transform, periodic-functions

I've a periodic function $y:[0,\infty]\to\mathbb{R}$ with a period of $T>0$. How can I prove the following equality:

> $$\int_0^\infty y(t)e^{-st}dt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_{nT}^{(n+1)T}y(t)e^{-st}dt$$

Answer (score 0):

The intervals $(nT,(n+1)T]$ are disjoint and their union is $(0,\infty)$. Periodicity is not involved in this.

Comment: So how can I prove the statement?

Comment: Just by noting that $[0,\infty) = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty [nT,(n+1)T)$ and using the dominanted convergence theorem. Of course, we need additional assumptations in order to guarantee the existence of the integral. For example, $f$ should be bounded and measurable.

Comment: @p4sch There is no way you can prove the existence of the integrals assuming only periodicity. I thought you were implicitly assuming that $y(t)e^{-st}$ is integrable on $(0,\infty)$. Under this hypothesis my argument is correct. Periodicity does not even make $y$ a measurable function  and the question makes no sense at all without further assumptions.

Comment: I have already written in my comment that 'we need additional assumptations in order to guarantee the existence of the integral. For example, f should be bounded and measurable." Of course, we could only assume that $y(t) \exp(-st)$ is integrable.

Answer (score 0):

Using that $f$ is periodic with a period $T>0$, we have additionally
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty f(t) \mathrm{e}^{-st} \, \mathrm{d} t &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{nT}^{(n+1)T} f(t)\mathrm{e}^{-st} \, \mathrm{d} t \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-nTs} \int_0^T f(h) e^{-sh} \mathrm{d} h \\
&= \frac{1}{1-\exp(-Ts)} \int_0^T f(h) e^{-sh} \mathrm{d} h.
\end{align}
This formula is more interesting, because we have now only the integration over one period involved.

**Edit:** As already commented, we need additional asumptations to guarantee the existence of the integral (in Lebesgue-sense). For example, we can assume that $f$ is measurable and bounded.